# Url amigável com pasta

Tags: php, htaccess

Eeu tenho a seguinte dúvida:

É possível transformar essa url: http://localhost/nomeprojeto/usercenter/index.php?user=home

Em: http://localhost/newera/user/home

Tem como fazer isso?
Eu tentei fazer isso no meu .htaccess e não consegui (Não sei quase nada sobre isso).

Obs: "usercenter" é uma pasta.

Answer (score 0):

Somente para o usuário `home`

```python
RewriteEngine On

# http://localhost/newera/user/home
# -->  http://localhost/nomeprojeto/usercenter/index.php?user=home
RewriteRule ^newera/user/home/?$ nomeprojeto/usercenter/index.php?user=home [NC,L,QSA]
```

Para qualquer texto:

```python
RewriteEngine On

# http://localhost/newera/user/qualquer-texto
# -->  http://localhost/nomeprojeto/usercenter/index.php?user=qualquer-texto
RewriteRule ^newera/user/([^/]+)/?$ nomeprojeto/usercenter/index.php?user=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```